# Apt-get can't find motion package 14.04

Tags: 14.04, server, apt, motion

I'm trying to install motion on ubuntu server 14.04 but apt-get can't find the package? From what i've read it should be able to find it. Please can someone point me in the direction of how to install it..

Comment: Make sure you enabled the `universe` repository.

Comment: Thanks but it looks enabled to me

Comment: Could you add the content of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` to your question?

Comment: Please run `sudo add-apt-repository universe ; sudo apt-get update -qq ; apt-cache policy motion` and paste the output to your question. You should be able to install it afterwards. If it worked, please notify me with a short comment and I will convert this into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up adding trusty-update and trusty-backports to /etc/apt/sources.list
 and and then added main, restricted, universe and multiverse to all of them

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted multiverse universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted multiverse universe

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted multiverse universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted multiverse universe

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted multiverse universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted multiverse universe

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports main restricted multiverse universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports main restricted multiverse universe
```